# I am having trouble while clicking a "Submit An App" button on my application which is present on the Menu bar

Tags: selenium, click

I am using the below code for this, this is present inside a frame and this also clicks the button but after button is clicked the control is lost. The possible reason i see is the page lands on same page which extra options after the "Submit An App" button is clicked.

I am using c# to code it. The first line finds the button the second line clicks but go for a timeout. I have seen this behavior fist time not sure how to work it out.

```
IWebElement field = VelocityDriver.FindElement(By.Id("AppSub"));
SeleniumExtensions.ClickElementAndContinue(field);
```

Comment: Is the site externally accessible? If so, can you post a link?

Comment: Can you show us what _ClickElementAndContinue()_ is all about?